# ConcurrentModificationException for Java LinkedList

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I have LinkedList of objects and an iterator. I know that this ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when you try to modify the list while running the iterator. But in my case, I don't understand where this modification is being done.

The iterator looks like this :

```
private static void insertTasks(Task t) {
    if(eventQueue.size() == 0) {
        eventQueue.addFirst(tsk);
        return;
    }

    int pos = 0;
    while (itr.hasNext()){
   //The line below throws the exception

        if (t.getArrivalTime() <= itr.next().getArrivalTime() ) 
        {           
            break;
        }
        pos++;
    }
}
```

I am calling this `insertTasks` method from another method as shown below :

```
tsk = null;
tsk = new Task(1,"P1",1,4.0f,1.5f,0.0f,8.0f);
insertTasks(tsk);

tsk = null;
tsk = new Task(0,"P0",2,5.0f,2.5f,1.0f,10.0f);
insertTasks(tsk);
```

The `getArrivalTime` in the `Task` objects looks like :

```
public float getArrivalTime() { return arrivalTime; }
```

My question is, where am I doing this modification ? The `while` loop where I run this `iterator` is not doing any modification. Does it ?

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Are you access it from more than one thread? Could you be modifying it in another thread elsewhere in the code while iterating?

Comment: No. I just have one `main` thread.

Comment: Can you provide a self contained example which reproduces the problem? It is likely you are changing the collection in code you haven't supplied.

Comment: BTW I would use `double` instead of `float` unless you have a really good reason to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reckon the problem is that `itr` is a static field in your class and that's creating the issue, as you're adding an element to `eventQueue` in your second call to `insertTasks()`.

Avoid static fields... program yourself to fear them and avoid them as much as you can :). They evil, and OO unfriendly.

Comment: But in the second call to `insertTasks` , the `eventQueue` is not modified. Since the `size()` of `eventQueue` is non zero after the first call. I debugged it too.

Comment: you're right. The problem is that on your first call to `insertTask()` you already created the iterator somewhere else, from an empty list. And now you're adding an element.

Comment: @gaganbm You initialized `itr` before the first call, so the first call invalidates the iterator by inserting an item, and the second call crashes after attempting to iterate.